# Is there a way to bundle PDF files into to a Kindle friendly file?

Tags: pdf, conversion, ebook, kindle, mobi

I'm downloading PDF approach plates from Navigraph, and I have a folder--per airport--with files named after their corresponding approach / departure etc.

Now I'd like to take such a folder with a bunch of PDF files, automatically generate an index and combine them to a single .mobi file that i can send to my Kindle.

The index created can be very simple and consist of the file name (without the extension). Tapping an index item should jump to the correct page for that chart.

I know there is a host of apps that combine comic book jpg's to ebooks, but is there anything - or another way - that does the above?

Comment: For a start: [PDF to Mobi converter](http://superuser.com/questions/25986/is-there-any-pdf-to-mobi-converter) - but I don't see an automatic index generation ability

Comment: You migth get more answers on the new [Ebook.SE](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/) site. If you're interested flag the question and request migration. http://meta.superuser.com/q/5336/95919

Comment: You would need to convert thepdfs to jpeg or png etc as puns can't contain pdfs. Kindle's can read pdfs so maybe make it one pdf